# Tilde accent marks alex

Tags: haskell, unicode, lexical-analysis, alex

I'm building a compiler in Haskell. I have problems parsing characters with tilde accent marks. I'm using alex 2.3.3.
I can't find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure are you parsing Unicode text?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The first thing you need to do after typing the words "I have problems" or "I get an error" is the explanation of what that problem or error is, including any **exact** error message you're getting. Your post as written now says "I'm having a problem parsing some unknown text with some code you can't see. How can I fix it?", which if course is impossible to do. Please edit your post to provide more information, and while you do remember that we can't read your mind or see your monitor from here (at least I can't <g>). The only info we have is what you give us. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode handling was quite restricted in alex before alex-3. In alex-3, afaik full unicode handling is implemented. There was some bug in alex-3.0.0 (I forgot what bug), so use alex-3.0.1.